# Parsing url and adding each subpath in an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing, url

I want to parse a URL and add each of its subpaths as an element in an array.

For example :

```
http://www.abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop.php
```

for this URL the array will look like:

```
[
  'http://www.abcd.com',
  'http://www.abcd.com/efgh',
  'http://www.abcd.com/efgh/ijkl',
  'http://www.abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop.php'
]
```

The problem is I am unable to add the exploded path to previous paths.

```
explode("/",parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH))
```

Comment: Did you try something so far? SO is not a place where people simple provide you with a solution!

Comment: i wan to help you, but i think @Vincent is right. it's not that tough.

Comment: i am not being able to explode  `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)` and add it accordingly @bugscoder

Comment: Based on that last comment, it sounds like you _do_ know how to do this. If you can show what you're doing currently that isn't working, I'm sure someone can explain why.

Comment: i will give you hint, you can try to explode the url and loop the array.

Comment: thanks @bugscoder can you upvote  it, i don't want to get banned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. You can break up the URL using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url). After exploding the path, I'm using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) to remove empties from the array, and [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to reset the keys.

```
$url = 'http://www.abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop.php';
$root = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . '://' . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$paths = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH))));

$arr[] = $root;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($paths); $i++) {
    $root .= '/' . $paths[$i];
    $arr[] = $root;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "http://www.abcd.com"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "http://www.abcd.com/efgh"
  [2]=>
  string(29) "http://www.abcd.com/efgh/ijkl"
  [3]=>
  string(38) "http://www.abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop.php"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By parsing the url, and then exploding the paths you can build out each path by looping through the paths.

```
function urlArrays($url)
{
    $paths = array();
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    if($parsed){
        $pathParts = explode("/",$parsed['path']);
        $current = $parsed['scheme'] . "://" . $parsed['host'];
        $paths[] = $current;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($pathParts); $i++)
        {
            if($pathParts[$i] != "")
            {
                $current = $current . "/" . $pathParts[$i];
                $paths[] = $current;
            }
        }
    }
    return $paths;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `parse_url` to build an array from the URL and `explode` function to split the `path` to an array and from there, you can loop through them and achieve what you're looking for. Here the code is:

```
function explode_url_path($url) {
    $url_parsed = parse_url($url);

    $url_scheme = $url_parsed['scheme'];
    $url_host = $url_parsed['host'];
    $url_path = $url_parsed['path'];

    $url_path_exploded = explode('/', ltrim($url_path, '/'));

    $url_array = array($url_scheme . "://" . $url_host);    
    $url_temp = $url_scheme . "://" . $url_host;

    foreach($url_path_exploded as $url_exploded) {
        $url_temp .= "/{$url_exploded}";
        $url_array[] = $url_temp;
    }

    return $url_array;
}

$url = 'http://www.abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop.php';
$url_exploded = explode_url_path($url);

var_dump($url_exploded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate method using [string access and modification by character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).

```
for ($i=0, $c=0, $path=''; isset($url[$i]); $path .= $url[$i++]) {
    if ($url[$i] == '/' && ++$c > 2) $paths[] = $path;
}
$paths[] = $url;
```

In this loop,

- `$i` is the current position in the string
- `$c` is a running total of
  `/` characters (to exclude the initial 2 after the scheme)
- `$path` is
  the path as it gets rebuilt one character at a time

Basically you iterate over the string by character (or byte, really) and whenever you encounter a `/` after the initial two, you append the current path to the array. After the loop you append the entire URL to complete the array.